# Excel formula for repeating sequence down column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Im looking for a formula which starting in C3, will repeat the numbers 9,12,15,18 sequentially down the column.

All help appreciated!

Comment: Please see my answer, i worked it out in the end with a combination of formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=9+3*MOD(ROW()-3,4)

Type this in C3 and fill down.

Answer (score 0):

Fill C3 with `9`, C4 with `12`, C5 with `15` and C6 with `18`

For C7:

`=c3`

then expand down.

Answer (score 0):

Fill **C3** with 9
**C4** with formula **=C3+3**
then expand **C4**

Comment: but c7 will show 21 instead of 9.

Answer (score -2):

I have done the following and found it works:

In C3: `=IF(MOD(30,5)=0,6,0)+3`
in C4: `=IF((MOD(9,3))=0,(C3+3),0)`
Then in C7: `=C3`

and filled down.